# deletion of records using dates

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql

i have a table as CostData in that i have a column as Month_year which is in mm/dd/yyyy format 
and now i want to delete data based on date. suppose i give start date as 01/31/2012
and end Date as 01/31/2013 it should delete whole one years record. and i have to text box's to take input of start and endDate

("Delete from CostData where Month_year between {0} and {1}'", TextBox2.Text, TextBox1.Text)

this is the query that I'm using, but its not working. Month_year is of date type.

Comment: What data type is Month_Year and in which RDBMS?

Comment: 'm using sql server 2008 and month_year is of date type

Comment: Nothing wrong with your query -- unless textbox values are off.  See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9717d/1 -- What does your SQL String evaluate to after it gets populated?

Comment: what error do you get? and correct me if I am wrong, does `{0}` work for parameterized queries I think that would be `@Month`

Comment: "m getting a error for the string so 'm not sure as what to use {0}0r ?? @spandy

Comment: @sgeddes after it gets populated i have to delete tat whole durations data

Comment: @sgeddes and thanks for the link you have provided it will be usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think you're issue is with your SQL String.  If you posted more of your code, I could tell for sure, but I suspect your using String.Format in the above?  If so, just wrap {0} and {1} around apostrophes:

```
("Delete from CostData where Month_year between '{0}' and '{1}'", TextBox2.Text, TextBox1.Text)
```

Please look into using parameterized queries -- this method is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Good luck.

Comment: Not sure I'm following you -- did you see my edits above with the exact string?

Comment: yes exactly :-) your rite that was the error with string. thank you very much. its working now. @sgeddes

Comment: @user1986144 -- no problem, glad we could help.  With that said, please do look into  parameterized queries as the above method is highly vulnerable to SQL Injection.  Do a quick search to see examples.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty, but I think it's something like this:

```
...where month(Month_year) => {0} and month(Month_year) <{1}
```

Comment: actually i have taken it as strings so it had to be '{0}' and '{1}'